# Embedding a leaflet map onto a blog

Tags: javascript, leaflet, image, html, embeddable-web-maps

I've created a leaflet map using maptiler.

It's created a leaflet HTML file, which links to PNG images on my desktop and displays the image.

How do I embed the map onto a blog such as tumblr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML page is on a server (even if it's on your desktop) ?
If not, you'll have to host it somewhere Tumblr/any other blog can reach.

Do not consider hosting it on your PC tho as you'll have to expose it publicly.

Once it has been done, just embeds an [**iframe**](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) in your blog page that will point to your leaflet HTML file. It will do it.